# Start instances of scheduled task at windows startup consuming same exe file

Tags: windows, task, exe, scheduler

I installed 3 scheduled task and triggered them with Windows startup.
After disabling hibernation, this worked fine only on one random task after several tries.

All of them consuming the same exe file with different parameter.
I then created 3 binary folders for 3 different locations of the exe file and its binaries and it turned out, that this works.

Problem is, that I want to create much more scheduled tasks with the same exe and calling with different arguments.

So the question is. Do I really have to copy new folders for every new task?

Comment: you can specify command line arguments when creating task. Also, If your program is hardcoded to use a fixed local parameters file, each task may have same binary executable location, and differents working directory with differents parameter files.

Comment: I do use command line arguments when I create and therefor call the task Problem is, this does not work on the same exe file.

Comment: in other word, exe can't be launched two time from same location. may be lock files created in exe folder or analog behavior. you must test it manualy. task scheduler is not the problem. application is the problem.